# doing select from stored procedure such as : select * from sp_tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, select

is there a way to simply select the result returned from sp_tables?

Comment: Your question doesn't wholly make sense - could you clarify please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't.

But you could try to replace sp_tables by querying the information_schema.

For example:

```
sp_tables 'T_Raum'
```

You can substitute with this:

```
SELECT 
TABLE_CATALOG AS TABLE_QUALIFIER, 
TABLE_SCHEMA AS TABLE_OWNER, 
TABLE_NAME, 
CASE TABLE_TYPE
        WHEN 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE'
        ELSE TABLE_TYPE
END AS TABLE_TYPE, 
NULL AS REMARKS 

FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

WHERE TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'T_Raum'
```

I don't know what exactly sp_tables does, or what you need it for, but at least in this case, it seems to do the above schema query.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `sp_tables`, the result you get **is** the result of a `SELECT` statement.

In that respect, it is no different than any store procedure that returns a result set.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to filter the resultset returned by that sproc then depending on what you want to filter on, you can pass in params to that sproc (e.g.  @table_name parameter, which supports wildcards). Check out the [BOL ref on sp_tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186250.aspx)

Alternatively, you will need to insert the results into a temp table and select from that.

Or finally, depending on what you want, you could query the sys tables directly. If only interested in tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE...
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to select from each table, you can use the undocumented `sp_msforeachtable` command:**

`sp_msforeachtable 'SELECT * FROM ?'`

The `?` is a wildcard that indicates the current table name, and the command needs to be a string enclosed in single quotes just like in other Dynamic SQL.

Comment: @none - you are welcome.  There is a related command, `sp_msforeachdb` which works for databases in the same way.  I've used them in combination before to run some logic on every table in every DB.

Comment: i just wonder if this could lead to a script that can backup all the databases to a specific drive. hmmm

Comment: @none - You can use it for whatever you want as long as it can be done from within a query.  You can also call stored procs this way using the DB name as a parameter.